# c# - CharacterToGlyphMap contains wrong code points of Unicode for some fonts

Tags: c#

I use CharacterToGlyphMap from GlyphTypeface

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms635034.aspx

to get all characters include in any fonts. If I use e.g. *Arial* everything is right, but for some fonts I get wrong code points.

For example for *Ebrima* I get some code points beyond of the scope of Unicode. The last character in Ebrima font is hex: FD3F (dec: 64831), but CharacterToGlyphMap contains a few additional values, e.g. (dec: 66688, 66689, 66690...). What could be the reason of wrong code points for above example?

**Edit:**

I implement my own character map and for some fonts my application crash, because I use

```
Convert.ToChar(unicodeCodePoint)
```

The solution for this problem is to limit the use of characters (thanks for @AakashM) e.g.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ushort> item in glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap)
{
   if (item.Key >= Char.MinValue && item.Key <= Char.MaxValue)
   {
      limitedCharacterMap.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
   }
}
```

Comment: What's your source for your statement "The last character in Ebrima font is hex: FD3F" ? (note that [Windows Character Map only supports the BMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755498) )

Comment: What do you mean with "beyond of the scope of Unicode"? Unicode does not stop at U+FFFF.

Comment: I create character map so I based on the built-in Windows. Thanks for the reply AakashM. Sebastian Negraszus you're right, my mistake.

Comment: @rgb add an answer explaining what you did and what you saw, it may help someone in the future.